# Punctuation question, 8th grade

Tags: punctuation

> Then Hitler came up with his "Final Solution" the Holocaust.

This sentence feels as if it needs something between "Final Solution," and the Holocaust, but I know it isn't a comma. Would it be a : or ;? If it is a comma, and I'm wrong, just let me know. I'm in 8th grade and I am working on a Holocaust project, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: A comma would be fine.  And just for the sake of historical accuracy, it was Heinrich Himmler, not Adolf Hitler, who came up with the "Final Solution."

Comment: The comma is perfect and neutral, matter-of-fact. The semicolon makes for a greater pause and effect; picture a short drumroll and decide for yourself if it's out of place given the context. The semicolon does not work at all. (The rule for using semicolons is simple: if you are not sure whether it works, then it does not.)

Comment: @Juhasz @RegDwigнt♦. Thanks! Perfect answer to my question.

Comment: Then Himmler came up with his "final solution": the extermination of the Jews. For your information, the Holocaust was not a term coined by Hitler or the nazis. And I most ***definitely*** would not honor it by capitalizing it!

Comment: Comma, `:`, or `--` all would work.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment,RegDwigнt wrote:

> The comma is perfect and neutral, matter-of-fact. The semicolon makes for a greater pause and effect; picture a short drumroll and decide for yourself if it's out of place given the context. The semicolon does not work at all. (The rule for using semicolons is simple: if you are not sure whether it works, then it does not.)

Comment: You say a semicolon makes for a greater pause and effect, then say that it does not work at all.